# Django __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have two models:

```
class Someinfo(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
#something else

class OtherInfo(models.Model):
name2 = models.CharField(max_lenth=200)
related_someinfo = models.ManyToManyField(Someinfo)
#something else
```

Now I have created CBV views to create and view them. The CreateView works fine and saves info that can be reviewed in admin, but I cannot get the template to display the data on any other view be it FormView, DetailView or any other, because I get this error:

```
__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://something
Django Version:     2.0.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py in get_initial_for_field, line 494
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.5.3
```

Checking the line in forms.py it shows that the function that is not working is:

```
def get_initial_for_field(self, field, field_name):
    """
    Return initial data for field on form. Use initial data from the form
    or the field, in that order. Evaluate callable values.
    """
    value = self.initial.get(field_name, field.initial)
    if callable(value):
        value = value()  # line 494
    return value
```

Any suggestions? I can query the linked objects via shell and they are saved in the database, so I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: You don't need to show the `forms.py` from Django - the error is probably caused by your code, which you haven't shown. Please add the views that are failing. It sounds like you might have form and model names clashing with each other, so if you use made-up names like `Someinfo` you might hide the problem.

Comment: Thenk you Alasdair, you saved me. My mistake was indeed in views.py. I was calling the initial data through m2m link directly not using .all().

Answer (score 37):

Here is my case, I am using django shell:

```sh
python manage.py shell
```

There are two models: `Topic` and `Entry`. I tried to get all `entries` from `Topic` which `id` is `1`.

```sh
>>> Topic.objects.get(id=1)
<Topic: Chess>
>>> t = Topic.objects.get(id=1)
>>> t.entry_set().all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
>>> t.entry_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Entry: Ah okey, so when testing for a console.log (or oth...>]>
>>>
```

The correct command is: `t.entry_set.all()`, not `t.entry_set().all()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's late, and I squinted at your answer for a couple of minutes trying to find a difference between the two, note for future self: No parentheses after field name

Answer (score 13):

Use `entry_set` instead of `entry_set()` (wihout brackets)